# Where does Ubuntu 22 store per-app sound volume settings?

Tags: sound, system-settings, volume-control

For some reason on Ubuntu 22, it keeps resetting my firefox volume to be 80% or so. I'd really like it to stay at 100%. I'm sure these values exist somewhere, so if someone could point me at them I'd go change/reset it.